# jQuery simple dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I want to make a simple dropdown menu but I can't make it so the sub-menus open one at a time. For example, when you open the second menu the first one closes and so on.

```js
$('#menu div').click(function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <div>Menu 1</div>
  <p> SOME TEXT </p>
  <div>Menu 2</div>
  <p> SOME TEXT </p>
  <div>Menu 3</div>
  <p> SOME TEXT </p>
  <div>Menu 4</div>
  <p> SOME TEXT </p>
  <div>Menu 5</div>
  <p> SOME TEXT </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you need simply call `slideUp()` on all the `p` elements which are not related to the `div` which was clicked:

```js
$('#menu div').click(function() { 
  let $target = $(this).next().slideToggle();
  $('#menu p').not($target).slideUp();
})
```

```css
p { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <div>Menu 1</div>
  <p> SOME TEXT </p>
  <div>Menu 2</div>
  <p> SOME TEXT </p>
  <div>Menu 3</div>
  <p> SOME TEXT </p>
  <div>Menu 4</div>
  <p> SOME TEXT </p>
  <div>Menu 5</div>
  <p> SOME TEXT </p>
</div>
```